# What is the correct way to initialize an array of pointer to struct?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

I am trying to implement trie data structure:-

```
typedef struct tries{
    char university[20];
    struct tries *path[10];
} tries;

tries* head = (tries*)malloc(sizeof(tries));
head->path = { NULL } ;
```

whenever I try to initialize all the elements of path array to NULL I am getting this error:-

```
clang -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow    tries.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o tries
tries.c:20:18: error: expected expression
    head->path = { NULL } ;
                 ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [tries] Error 1
```

how can I initialize all path array's elements to NULL
I am using this NULL value in my Insert and Search functions.

```
void Search(char* university, char* year, tries* head){
    int pos = 0;
    int length = strlen(year);
    tries* temp = head;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++){
        pos = (int) (year[i]%48);

        if(temp->path[pos] != NULL){
            temp = temp->path[pos];
        } else {
            printf("%s Not Found !!\n", university);
            return;
        }

    }

    if(strcmp(temp->university, university) == 0){
        printf("%s is Presnt.\n", university);
    } else {
        printf("%s Not Found !\n", university);
    }

}
```

Comment: C does not allow assigning to array.

Comment: The use of `48`  in `year[i]%48` is curious.

Comment: The year char will contain a value like "1994" so while accessing position one by one I am left with the char values and they have their equivalent ASCII values starting from 48 that is for 0 and 49 for 1, 50 for 2 and so on respectively. Now by moding it with 48, i will get pos values ranging from 0-9 those are the positions that will hold values of the pointers to new nodes that I will create, in the array for pointers to the structs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `calloc()` instead of `malloc()` and you'll get all `0`s in the the `char`-array and all `NULL`s into the pointer-array.

Change

```
tries * head = (tries*)malloc(sizeof(tries));
```

to be

```
tries * head = (tries*)calloc(1, sizeof(tries));
```

Also please note that

- there is no need to cast `void`-pointer in C
- `sizeof` is an operator not a function

so just do:

```
tries * head = calloc(1, sizeof (tries));
```

And if you want this code line to be more robust, surviving  the change of the type `head` points to make it

```
tries * head = calloc(1, sizeof *head);
```

---

As you are dealing with `struct`s which in fact are assignable you could do the following:

```
const tries init_try = {0};

...

  tries * head = malloc(sizeof *head);
  if (NULL == head)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  *head = init_try;
```

Comment: UV for `*alloc(... sizeof *head);` idiom.